# Positional Bathroom Etiquette

Tags: code-golf

#### Background

Bathroom Etiquette, when pertaining to the available urinals, states that the next urinal to be filled in should be the one that minimizes the total discomfort. The total discomfort equation is given by the following set of equations:

```
dist(x,y) = linear distance between person x and person y in Urinal Units
discomfort(x) = sum(1/(dist(x,y)*dist(x,y))) for all persons y excluding person x
total_Discomfort = sum(discomfort(x)) for all x
```

A more in depth paper dealing with a similar (not the exact same) problem can be found here: [(Thanks to @Lembik for alerting me to this amazing whitepaper!)](http://people.scs.carleton.ca/~kranakis/Papers/urinal.pdf)

---

#### Input/Output

Given an input of a empty and full urinals, output the resulting set of urinals with the addition of one person. If there is a tie for a position the urinals should fill in left to right. The output should be in the same format as the input.

- If given a case with full urinals, return the input.
- The input will always have at least one urinal defined.

---

#### Test Cases

```
INPUT     -> OUTPUT
1000001   -> 1001001
101010101 -> 111010101
100       -> 101
00000     -> 10000
1111111   -> 1111111
0100      -> 0101
101000    -> 101001
```

---

#### Rules

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins. Standard loop-holes are forbidden.

Comment: Related problem: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/47952/the-urinal-protocol

Comment: It is recommended to wait about a week before accepting an answer. Accepting in less than a day might decrease the amount of answers your challenge receives.

Comment: I'd suggest adding `0100` and `101000` in the test cases (some regex-based approach work on the actual test cases but won't work on those ones which should still be handled)

Comment: also related: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/94074/checkmate-aka-the-urinal-problem

Comment: @TheBitByte How is it offensive? It's a pretty accurate description of how men choose urinals in a bathroom.

Comment: @TheBitByte Good thing no bodily fluids have been mentioned. "Urinal" is not offensive in any way. Deal with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>13</s> 12 bytes

```
J_þTİ²SiṂ$Ṭo
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=Sl_DvlTEsMKyU2nhuYIk4bmsbw&input=&args=WzEsIDAsIDEsIDAsIDEsIDAsIDEsIDAsIDFd) or [Verify all test cases.](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=Sl_DvlTEsMKyU2nhuYIk4bmsbwrDh-KCrA&input=&args=W1sxLCAwLCAwLCAwLCAwLCAwLCAxXSwgWzEsIDAsIDEsIDAsIDEsIDAsIDEsIDAsIDFdLCBbMSwgMCwgMF0sIFswLCAwLCAwLCAwLCAwXSwgWzEsIDEsIDEsIDEsIDEsIDEsIDFdXQ)

### Explanation

```
J_þTİ²SiṂ$Ṭo  Input: boolean array A
J             Indices, returns [1, 2, ..., len(A)]
   T          Truthy indices, returns the indices which have a truthy value
 _þ           Form the subtraction (_) table (þ) between them
    İ         Inverse, find the reciprocal of each
     ²        Square each
      S       Sum the sublists column-wise
         $    Monadic chain
        Ṃ       Minimum
       i        Find the first index of that
          Ṭ   Untruth indices, returns a boolean array with 1's at those indices
           o  Logical OR between that and A, and return
```

Answer (score 11):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>19</s> <s>18</s> 17 bytes

```
lyf!Gn:-H_^Xs&X<(
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=bHlmIUduOi1IX15YcyZYPCg&input=WzEgMCAwIDAgMCAwIDFd) Or [verify all test cases](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=YApseVhLZiFLbjotSF9eWHMmWDwoCkRU&input=WzEgMCAwIDAgMCAwIDFdClsxIDAgMSAwIDEgMCAxIDAgMV0KWzEgMCAwXQpbMCAwIDAgMCAwXQpbMSAxIDEgMSAxIDEgMV0) (slightly modified code).

#### Explanation

It suffices to compute the distance from each potential new position to the already occupied ones. The remaining distances are do not depend on the potential new position, and so constitute a constant term, which can be ignored.

Let's take input `[1 0 0 0 0 0 1]` as an example.

```
l      % Push 1
       % STACK: 1
y      % Take input implicitly. Duplicate from below
       % STACK: [1 0 0 0 0 0 1], 1, [1 0 0 0 0 0 1]
f!     % Indices of nonzero elements, as a column array
       % STACK: [1 0 0 0 0 0 1], 1, [1 7]
Gn:    % Push [1 2 ... n], where n is input size (array of possible positions)
       % STACK: [1 0 0 0 0 0 1], 1, [1; 7], [1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
-      % Matrix with all pairs of differences 
       % STACK: [1 0 0 0 0 0 1], 1, [1; 7], [0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6;
                                             6  5  4  3  2  1  0]
H_^    % Raise each entry to -2
       % STACK: [1 0 0 0 0 0 1], 1, [   Inf 1.0000 0.2500 0.1111 0.0625 0.0400 0.0278;
                                     0.0278 0.0400 0.0625 0.1111 0.2500 1.0000    Inf]
Xs     % Sum of each column
       % STACK: [1 0 0 0 0 0 1], 1, [Inf 1.04 0.3125 0.2222 0.3125 1.04 Inf]
&X<    % Index of minimum. Takes the first if there is a tie
       % STACK: [1 0 0 0 0 0 1], 1, 4
(      % Assign: write 1 at the position of the minimizer
       % STACK: [1 0 0 1 0 0 1]
       % Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (ES6), 89 bytes

```
a=>a[a.map((e,i)=>!e&&(t=0,a.map((e,j)=>t+=(j-=i)&&e/j/j),t<m&&(m=t,k=i)),k=0,m=1/0),k]=1
```

Outputs by modifying the input array.

Answer (score 4):

## R, <s>83</s> <s>76</s> 67 bytes

Just realized that I can save several bytes by not bothering to check if the candidate urinals are empty. Non-empty urinals will always return an `Inf` discomfort value, so they're excluded in the course of the calculation. Also, just using direct indexing rather than `replace`, so it's shorter but less elegant.

```
x=scan()
x[which.min(rowSums(outer(seq(x),which(!!x),`-`)^-2))]=1
x
```

#### Explanation

```
x=scan()
```

We read the current state from stdin and call it `x`. We assume that the input is a sequence of `1`s and `0`s separated by spaces or newlines. For the purposes of the explanation, let's say we input `1 0 0 0 0 0 1`.

```
x[which.min(rowSums(outer(seq(x),which(!!x),`-`)^-2))]=1
```

We replace a value of `x` at a particular index with 1. Everything between the `[ ]` is figuring out what the best index is.

Since the existing urinals are immutable, we don't need to consider the distances between them. We only need to consider the distances between the occupied urinals and the possible new one. So we determine the indices of the occupied urinals. We use `which`, a function to return the indices of a logical vector which are `TRUE`. All numbers in R, when coerced to type `logical`, are `TRUE` if nonzero and `FALSE` if zero. Simply doing `which(x)` will result in a type error, `argument to 'which' is not logical`, as `x` is a numeric vector. We therefore have to coerce it to logical. `!` is R's logical negation function, which automatically coerces to logical. Applying it twice, `!!x`, yields a vector of `TRUE` and `FALSE` indicating which urinals are occupied. (Alternative byte-equivalent coercions to logical involve the logical operators `&` and `|` and the builtins `T` and `F`, e.g. `F|x` or `T&x` and so on. `!!x` looks more exclamatory so we'll use that.)

```
                                 which(!!x)
```

This is paired with `seq(x)`, which returns the integer sequence from `1` to the length of `x`, i.e. all urinal locations (and thus all possible locations to consider).

```
                          seq(x)
```

Now we have the indices of our occupied urinals: `1 7` and our empty urinals `1 2 3 4 5 6 7`. We pass `` `-` ``, the subtraction function, to the `outer` function to get the "outer subtraction", which is the following matrix of distances between all urinals and the occupied urinals:

> [,1] [,2]
>
> [1,]    0   -6
>
> [2,]    1   -5
>
> [3,]    2   -4
>
> [4,]    3   -3
>
> [5,]    4   -2
>
> [6,]    5   -1
>
> [7,]    6    0

```
                    outer(seq(x),which(!!x),`-`)
```

We raise this to the `-2`th power. (For those who are a little lost, in the OP, "discomfort" is defined as `1 / (distance(x, y) * distance(x, y))`, which simplifies to `1/d(x,y)^2`, i.e. `d(x,y)^-2`.)

```
                    outer(seq(x),which(!!x),`-`)^-2
```

Take the sum of each row in the matrix.

```
            rowSums(outer(seq(x),which(!!x),`-`)^-2)
```

Get the index of the smallest value, i.e. the optimal urinal. In the case of multiple smallest values, the first (i.e. leftmost) one is returned.

```
  which.min(rowSums(outer(seq(x),which(!!x),`-`)^-2))
```

And voilà, we have the index of the optimal urinal. We replace the value at this index in `x` with `1`. In the case of `1111` as input, it doesn't matter which one we replace, we'll still have a valid output.

```
x[which.min(rowSums(outer(seq(x),which(!!x),`-`)^-2))]=1
```

Return the modified input.

```
x
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3 <s>223</s> <s>222</s> 165 Bytes

Okay, I know this isn't the prettiest answer out there, and I'm sure it can be golfed down quite a bit, but I was just messing around and seeing what I could do

Shout out to mbomb007 for the tips on whitespace and comparators
Also, I saw my online character counter was taking all the tabs and turning them into spaces, so the count is a lot less than I originally had

```
def u(a):
 m,r,x=9,0,len(a)
 for i in range(x): 
    d=0
    if a[i]<'1':
     for j in range(x):
        if a[j]>'0':d+=float((j-i)**-2)
     if d<m:r=i;m=d
 return a[:r]+'1'+a[r+1:]
```

Showing revised whitespace:

```
def u(a):
<sp> m,r,x=9,0,len(a)
<sp> for i in range(x): 
<tab> d=0
<tab> if a[i]<'1':
<tab><sp> for j in range(x):
<tab><tab> if a[j]>'0':d+=float((j-i)**-2)
<tab><sp> if d<m:r=i;m=d
<sp> return a[:r]+'1'+a[r+1:]
```

Original:

```
def u(a):
    m,r,x=9,0,len(a)
    for i in range(x): 
        d=0
        if a[i]!='1':
            for j in range(x):
                if a[j]=='1':d+=float(1/(j-i)**2)
            if d<m:r=i;m=d
    return a[:r]+'1'+a[r+1:]
```

This expects a string passed to it of 1's and 0's like `"10001"` and returns a string `"10101"`

Edit: Changed `1/float((j-i)**2)` to `float((j-i)**-2)`

Comment: `!='1'` can be `<'1'` and `=='1'` can be `>'0'`. Also, consider [this tip](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/58/34718)

Comment: Thanks for that whitespace tip. I definitely did not know that. That's awesome!

Comment: That whitespace tip only works in Python 2, I think. Maybe early version of Python 3, but idk. You'll have to restrict your answer to Python 2 or some specific version of 3 with it working.

Comment: I've got it running in a 3.5.2 shell in IDLE and it's running without an issue, so I think it's alright still

Answer (score 2):

### PHP, 135  bytes

```
$a=explode(1,$argv[1]);$b=0;foreach($a as$c=>$d){$l=strlen($d);if($l>$b){$b=$l;$e=$c;}}if($b)$a[$e][intval($b/2)]=1;echo implode(1,$a);
```

I'm sure there's a considerably quicker way of doing it, but I've got a fuzzy head and can't think of one!

#### Old code

The code without minification:

```
$a=explode(1,$argv[1]);
$b=0;
foreach($a as $c=>$d){
    $l=strlen($d);
    if($l>$b){
        $b=$l;
        $e=$c;
    }
}
if($b){
    $a[$e][intval($b/2)]=1;
}
echo implode(1,$a);
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, <s>574</s> <s>471</s> 347 bytes

I'll probably work on this some more, considering the other Python solution is like a fifth of this one :[.

```
def a(I):
 D,l,r={},len(I),range
 for i in r(l):
  if I[i]<1:
   n,t,n[i]=I[:],[],1
   for j in r(l):
    if n[j]>0:
     q,Q=[],0
     for k in r(l):
      if k!=j and n[k]>0:q.append((k-j,j-k)[k<j])
     for i in q:Q+=1/(i**2)
    t.append(Q)
   T=sum(t)
   if T not in D.keys():D[T]=i
 if len(D)>0:I[D[min(D.keys())]]=1
 print(I)
```

Well that's much better now that I've learned you can use single spaces.

Answer (score 1):

## Python, <s>165</s> <s>163</s> <s>158</s> <s>147</s> <s>141</s> <s>140</s> 139 bytes

```
def u(p):e=enumerate;a=[(sum((i-j)**-2for j,y in e(p)if"0"<y),i)for i,x in e(p)if"1">x];return a and p[:min(a)[1]]+"1"+p[min(a)[1]+1:] or p
```

Comment: rewrite second line as `if"1"*len(p)==p:return p` to save a byte

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 18 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
$āsƶ0Kδ-znD_°+OWkǝ
```

I/O as a list.

Port of [*@miles*' Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/98240/52210), so make sure to upvote that answer as well!
Unfortunately, dividing by 0 won't result in `INF` in 05AB1E like it does in Jelly and MATL, but instead in `0`. So 4 bytes (`D_°+`) are to account for that..

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f5Uhj8bFtBt7ntuhW5bnEH9qg7R@efXzu///RhjoGOig4FgA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfaXLf8PiI43Fx7YZeJ/boluV5xJ/aIO2f3j28bn/df5HRxvqGMChYawOmI@CoWIGQBquEiyGBMFyhnAZKBvIiwUA).

**Explanation:**

```python
$                  # Push 1 and the input-list
 ā                 # Push a list in the range [1,length] (without popping the list)
  s                # Swap so the input-list is at the top again
   ƶ               # Multiply each value by its 1-based index
    0K             # Remove all 0s
      δ-           # Pop both lists, and create a subtraction table
        z          # Convert each inner value to 1/value
         n         # Square each inner value
          D        # Duplicate this list
           _       # Check for each inner value whether it equals 0 (1 if 0; 0 otherwise)
            °      # Take 10 to the power this (10 if 0; 1 otherwise)
             +     # Add it to each value at the same positions
              O    # Sum each inner list
               W   # Push the minimum (without popping the list)
                k  # Pop both, and push the (first) (0-based) index of this minimum
                 ǝ # Insert the 1 at this index into the (implicit) input-list
                   # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 173 bytes

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVDLboMwELzzFatc8AqT2L0V4kj5gJ6qnqoenBgSIx6RgTQt4tupeahKCxlbsrQ7o5lxeZSp7IpDEh0reJE6h8Zx4CpTqAPyWhmdn8RufBFEJ8WuuUpDMmrojSoU5FlRRuW61N8RZQrDuDBEb30GVQE3n6OOiSQahXCZi40SbGAk/xlJz@AuKk9ksjqvL8UnSXxN/ScMLUFtM2yM0GEmVNuG1q8@lEMqwqhBz0q9@6HxOLYdgIpiyGwrIs2pDGBvjPx6H@t8YABvua5A2MpgcbHTKs1JTVac9eArxH6x2UB5LupUjZQA7Lq/c9V0Bt1cxaf1gtvk9MBtphji/WqW8jE2cxnxsNOImdOfcDPVch1@l26pzvh3rdN2Pw)

```scala
a=>{var(m,r,x,d)=(9d,0,a.size,0d);for(i<-0 to x-1)if(a(i)=='0'){d=0;for(j<-0 to x-1)if(a(j)=='1')d+=math.pow(j-i,-2);if(d<m){r=i;m=d}};a.substring(0,r)+'1'+a.substring(r+1)}
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVHLboMwELzzFaNcYisJMb01Cod@QE9VT1UPToDEEY/ImD5U8e3Uxg4hMizI9nh3Zne99ZHnvOuqwyU9KrxyUeIvAJI0Q0P4Dm9KivJEbwfEvRv44hKFRs8hG7DU@IZy/GjEwzwtT@rcX2aVBBHYb8DQlEroEOrULD8xfKcHiAyEE0ERx1iy5T3UKV1mlO7ci@VGy0en7g6rGAVX5/BafWuhDcQamyc6CmoD/2RUE@xRPOqZtsUIm2dJPLrd7crDujnU/YMStoakWJky9Tr2SI0jU1MbuIkUejyEy1O9w4uU/PfDDuVTj@e9FGoYzlXfqrwkDVlEzFi0oNQ4tlvU56rJExuyg3ab32e5r@f5rMi5J7K5TDPZPEZf3sCZqo8xL4u12Z6seZkeivNY0@1Eo@qm2rFv1wZt1/0D)

```scala
object Main {
  def u(a: String): String = {
    var m = 9.0
    var r = 0
    val x = a.length
    for (i <- 0 until x) {
      var d = 0.0
      if (a(i) == '0') {
        for (j <- 0 until x) {
          if (a(j) == '1') {
            d += math.pow(j - i, -2)
          }
        }
        if (d < m) {
          r = i
          m = d
        }
      }
    }
    a.substring(0, r) + '1' + a.substring(r + 1)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(u("1000001"))    // should print: 1001001
    println(u("101010101"))  // should print: 111010101
    println(u("100"))        // should print: 101
    println(u("00000"))      // should print: 10000
    println(u("1111111"))    // should print: 1111111
    println(u("0100"))       // should print: 0101
    println(u("101000"))     // should print: 101001
  }
}
```