# The number of solutions to Hertzsprung's Problem

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence, integer, combinatorics

[Hertzprung's Problem (OEIS A002464)](https://oeis.org/A002464) is the number of solutions to a variant of the [Eight Queens Puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle), where instead of placing \$n\$ queens, you place \$n\$ rook-king fairy pieces (can attack like both a rook and a king); in other words, it's how many possible positions you can place \$n\$ rook-kings on an \$n \times n\$ board such that each piece does not occupy a neighboring square (both vertically, horizontally, and diagonally).

### Challenge

Write the **shortest** function or full program that will output the number of solutions to Hertzprung's Problem.

You may either:

- output just \$\operatorname{A002464}(n)\$, given a positive integer \$n > 0\$, or
- output all terms of \$\operatorname{A002464}(k) \text{ where } 0 < k < \infty\$ as a [sequence](/questions/tagged/sequence).

### Notes

- A formula is derived in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qt5I1gZj1ew):
  $$
  \operatorname{A002464}(n) = n! + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (-1)^k(n-k)!\sum_{r=1}^k 2^r \binom{n-k}{r} \binom{k-1}{r-1}
  $$

### Test Cases

```
1:  1
2:  0
3:  0
4:  2
5:  14
6:  90
23: 3484423186862152966838
```

Comment: Can you simply print all values one by one infinitely like a [tag:sequence] instead of taking a input?

Comment: @mousetail yes that's acceptable

Comment: I had this weird dream last night that I wrote a PPCG question based on a men's restroom - each man won't stand directly next to the previous man to arrive because it makes them look like they're a stalker, in which case in how many ways can `n` men fill `n` urinals?

Comment: The formula is incorrect. Instead of summing from i=0 to k-1, it needs to be from 1 to k-1, with an extra n! added to the whole thing in lieu of the k=0 entry (which works out to 0 as written). See the pinned comment on the Another Roof video.

Comment: @MarkReed fixed

Comment: @Neil it already exists: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/47952/the-urinal-protocol and https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/120379/the-halftime-hustle/120383 and https://blog.xkcd.com/2009/09/02/urinal-protocol-vulnerability/ and https://www.codingame.com/training/medium/the-optimal-urinal-problem (last one is my question)

Comment: @justhalf I am aware of other urinal protocols but those are different from the one in my dream whose solution is exactly the same as this question.

Comment: ah, didn't catch your intention. Nice one!

Answer (score 9):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata) + `-n`, 6 bytes

```
r↕∆A1>
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFNtJJurpKOgpJunlLsgqWlJWm6FquKHrVNfdTR5mhot6Q4KbkYKrxgtSGXEZcxlwmXKZcZRAgA)

Brute force. Slow for large input.

```
r↕∆A1>
r↕      Find a permutation of [0..n-1] such that
  ∆A    the absolute differences of adjacent elements
    1>  are all greater than 1
```

The flag `-n` count possible solutions.

Comment: Does Nekomata support recursion? I can't find it in docs

Comment: @lesobrod Not yet.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

<sup>I almost asked this question after watching Another Roof's video.</sup>

```
Œ!IỊ§¬S
```

A monadic Link that accepts \$n\$ and yields the number of solutions.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///oJEXPh7u7Di0/tCb4////ZgA)**

#### How?

```
Œ!IỊ§¬S - Link: non-negative integer, n  e.g. 4
Œ!      - all permutations (of [1..n])        [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,4,3],...,[2,4,1,3],...,[3,1,4,2],...,[4,3,2,1]]
  I     - forward differences                 [[1,1,1],[1,2,-1],...,[2,-3,2],...,[-2,3,-2],...[-1,-1,-1]]
   Ị    - insignificant?                      [[1,1,1],[1,0,1],...,[0,0,0],...,[0,0,0],...[1,1,1]]
    §   - sums                                [3,2,...,0,...,0,...3]
     ¬  - logical NOT                         [0,0,...,1,...,1,...,0]
      S - sum                                 2
```

...yes, it also works if \$n=0\$ (the alternative of `Œ!IỊ§ċ0` would give \$0\$ rather than \$1\$).

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands/2649a799300cbf3770e2db37ce177d4a19035a25), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Lœ¥Ä≠PO
```

Port of [*@alephalpha*'s Nekomata answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/260270/52210), so also a slow brute-force for larger inputs.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f5@jkQ0sPtzzqXBDg//@/GQA) or [verify most test cases](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/W/uU1Zpr6Sga6egZF/53@fo5ENLD7c86lwQ4P9f5z8A).

**Explanation:**

```python
L       # Push a list in the range [1, (implicit) input-integer]
 œ      # Get all permutations of this list
  ¥     # † For each inner permutation-list: get its deltas / forward-differences
   Ä    # Get the absolute value of each inner-most difference
    ≠   # Check for each that it's NOT 1 (so basically >= 2)
     P  # Product on each inner list, to check for which all overlapping pairs are >=2
      O # Take the sum, to check how many are truthy
        # (after which it is output implicitly as result)
```

† Uses the legacy version of 05AB1E to save 1 byte, because `¥` vectorizes on a list of lists, whereas the new 05AB1E version would give an error, and would require an additional `€` before the `¥` to accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

## [><> (Fish)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 60 bytes

```
11005:&$:@*3[{:}]&3-:&*-4[{:}]&3-:&*-5[{:}]&2+:&*+:nao&5+40.
```

[Try it](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiMTEwMDU6JiQ6QCozW3s6fV0mMy06JiotNFt7On1dJjMtOiYqLTVbezp9XSYyKzomKis6bmFvJjUrNDAuIiwiaW5wdXQiOiIiLCJzdGFjayI6IiIsInN0YWNrX2Zvcm1hdCI6Im51bWJlcnMiLCJpbnB1dF9mb3JtYXQiOiJjaGFycyJ9)

Infinitely prints values starting at n=4.

Based on the recursive formula pioneered by [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/260269/91213) but instead of recursing just keeps previous values pushed to the stack.

Answer (score 2):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 69 bytes

```
K=n-k+1
f(n)=n!-∑_{k=2}^n(-1)^kK!∑_{a=1}^k2^anCr(K,a)nCr(k-2,a-1)
```

Nice.

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/shvdjovqiy)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rdi9psqmwx)

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 125 bytes

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/P600L7kkMz9PwV1DJVOzOjMNSCno5pQomCBzjDSrDWtTc4pTqw1qITRQRttQU0sDpE3XUFNTF0QbwQSMoAKmMAFjTU1tCA0VMNHUrK39765hofkfAA)

Golfed Version:

```
function G($i){if($i -lt 4){if($i -lt 2){1}else{0}}else{($i+1)*(G($i-1))-($i-2)*(G($i-2))-($i-5)*(G($i-3))+($i-3)*(G($i-4))}}
```

Un-Golfed Version:

```
function G($i){
if($i -lt 4)
    {if($i -lt 2){1}
    else{0}
}else{
    ($i+1)*(G($i-1))-($i-2)*(G($i-2))-($i-5)*(G($i-3))+($i-3)*(G($i-4))
}
}
```

Let me know of any improvements!

Answer (score 2):

## [Aussie++](https://github.com/zackradisic/aussieplusplus/), 136 bytes

Tested in commit 9522366. Loses precision for inputs >18, because all numbers are doubles.

```
THE HARD YAKKA FOR a IS(n)<YA RECKON n <2?BAIL 1;YA RECKON n <4?BAIL 0;BAIL(n +1)*a(n -1)-(n -2)*a(n -2)-(n -5)*a(n -3)+(n -3)*a(n -4);>
```

Aussie++ requires every identifier to be followed by whitespace, a semicolon, a comma, or a paren, so I can't remove the spaces before all the operators. It also doesn't have bitwise operators, and the equivalent to `--` is `PULL YA HEAD IN`, so I can't take the same shortcuts as the JS and C answers.

Example test code:

```
G'DAY MATE!

THE HARD YAKKA FOR a IS(n)<YA RECKON n <2?BAIL 1;YA RECKON n <4?BAIL 0;BAIL(n +1)*a(n -1)-(n -2)*a(n -2)-(n -5)*a(n -3)+(n -3)*a(n -4);>

I RECKON i IS A WALKABOUT FROM [0 TO 18] <
  GIMME "" + i + ": " + a(i);
>

CHEERS C***!
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `Rl`, 36 bits<sup>1</sup>, 4.5 [bytes](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md)

```
Ṗ'¯ȧċA
```

[Try it Online! (link is to bitstring)](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=1#WyJSbEEhIiwiIiwiMTEwMTAxMTAwMTAxMDEwMDEwMTExMDAxMTExMDAwMTEwMTEwIiwiIiwiMVxuMlxuM1xuNFxuNVxuNiJd)

Port of [Kevin Cruijssen's 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/260299/114970), which is in turn a port of [alephalpha's Nekomata answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/260270/52210). Like those, it is a brute force solution, suffering with the same slowdown on larger inputs.

```
Ṗ      # permutations of the range 1..n (due to the R flag)
 '     # filtered by
  ¯ȧ   # absolute value of the deltas
     A # are all
    ċ  # not 1
       # the length of this filtered list is taken by the l flag
       # and implicitly output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 51 bytes

```
n->Vec(sum(i=0,n,i!*(x*(1-x)/(1+x))^i)+O(x^n++))[n]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMHiNAXbpaUlaboWN43zdO3CUpM1iktzNTJtDXTydDIVtTQqtDQMdSs09TUMtSs0NeMyNbX9NSri8rS1NTWj82KhWo0SCwpyKjXyFHTtFAqKMvNKgEwlEEdJIU0jT1NTRyHaUMdIx1jHRMdUx0zHyDhWE6JzwQIIDQA)

Based on the generating funtion on the OEIS page.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 56 bytes

Based on the recurrence formula provided on [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A002464).

```javascript
f=n=>n<4?n/2^1:-~n--*f(n--)-n*f(n)-(n-3)*f(--n)+n*f(n-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYyxDoJAEER7v2ILkuMkiwGsgINQoLGQQi2sBEQwGtwzoDYEfv0EYzN58zKZe/7J26K5PV9I8lIqVQkSAfnLkBb2yXJxIMR5pY/JkSbgOBaHj4hI3Pg5tLiqZKMTCLA8IPAF2M4IhsGhmwEUklpZl2Ytr3qW61pHPQetm@4ggOT9OJeNuY2O6T5axekmOcTreAchsEEwcIEJ1v/nfca9Wa@@)

#### With Bigints, 58 bytes

```javascript
f=n=>n<4?n/2n^1n:-~n--*f(n--)-n*f(n--)-~-~-n*f(n)+n--*f(n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYtBCsIwFET3PcVfdJFviNLqyjZ6E2mojShlvrTiJqRXj6koA8MbZubh3m7up/vzZSDXISVvYU9oD2fsalwqHM0CYzZeZWeDPyxZ38D6V3PyMimQpQoNgVpL9X4lrZlCQdQLZhmH7Sg31TlVBkTO6zKs59hxU8T0AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>60</s></sup> 58 bytes

```c
f(n){n=n<4?n<2:-~n--*f(n--)-n*f(n)-(n-3)*f(--n)+n*f(n-1);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU/bboMwDH3vV1hIlQiNNS7tpA7YHqZ9xeABhdChbW5FMg0NsU8fM5SidZFj2cfnODkKD0oNQ@WS6CilZPtASXiH34ToMYgokMZCIDeR4BKRxGbCMBBxP9Rk4b2oyRXQrYDPCFhtrHnOIYUukBBKiCRsJewk3PbxwtLtSSury4XoT8H0gMl7f6aqIxkL6qVoPM5avermrHCy9inM2v0j350j4W8fObO6Ojbgjq/VVOqWZX48lwmY@ksfK/fyD3EzA96CxLDZTOyLu8Uhbzq7nMZ5fDU1PK1cK65Rzeji@b/s1DClcp11CXgPnNcmIzZlJRi5@DZpqvN5bT/lRtuPhtjVqh9@VPVWHMyAn78)

*Port of [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)'s [JavaScipt answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/260269/9481).*

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)*

Comment: In C, you can just use `n<2` instead of `n/2^1`. (I could do that in JS as well, but that would output Boolean values, which is a bit weird.)

Comment: @Arnauld One certainly can - thanks! :D

Answer (score 1):

## Raku, 132 bytes

Translated the (corrected) formula directly; not particularly golfed, just crunched out all the unnecessary whitespace:

```
->\n{[*](1..n)+[+]((1..n-1).map: ->\k{(-1)**k*[*](1..n -k)*[+]((1..k).map: ->\r{2**r*combinations(n -k,r)*combinations(k-1,r-1)})})}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7X5xYqaDxX9cuJq86WitWw1BPL09TO1o7VgPM1DXU1MtNLLBSACrIrtYAcrW0srVgChV0szW1YGqzESqLqo20tIq0kvNzkzLzEksy8/OKNUCKdYo0UQWzdQ11ioCG1oLgf00NU83/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 34 bytes

```
Ｆ⁴⊞υ‹ι²ＦＮ⊞υΣ×⮌υ⟦⁺⁵ι±⁺²ι⁻¹ι⊕ι⟧Ｉ§υ±⁴
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RY89CsJAEIV7T7GkmoWkMKgIVmIV0BDULqRINhNdSFbZ2RXvYhNB0QN4GW9j_sDyffPxHnN7i2OqxSkt6_ppTeHNv5_ipBlMOIssHcG6bI1EIF3mc74YdcdAna0JbZWhBv4Xd7aCvayQYIsX1IRgucviqLQEU5fJJoR4SA1Ch_wWNWwjVZPGvRAoobFCZTAHyRPebkZaKgOrlAwsTaByvLZrQ9WEt86DMkHDB6_Y8S6lk9xnff4B) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs the `n`th element. Explanation:

```
Ｆ⁴⊞υ‹ι²
```

Start with the first four values (0-indexed, so `1, 1, 0, 0`).

```
ＦＮ⊞υΣ×⮌υ⟦⁺⁵ι±⁺²ι⁻¹ι⊕ι⟧
```

Use the recurrence relation to calculate `n` more values.

```
Ｉ§υ±⁴
```

Output the `4`th last value.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-x`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 10 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
õ á Ëäa eÉ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LXg&code=9SDhIMvkYSBlyQ&input=Ng)

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 97 bytes

Based on the recurrence formula provided by [A002464](https://oeis.org/A002464).

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZFBTsMwEEX3OcVX1IWHJihJUySqFoklC1aIFWJhEqcYglvFFiqKcgrEjtNxkTBx2lKkeEZ/5o397dhC1rLfPL2owuFWaoO2L1WFSpjFjXE0hJVmtcyp9TmjFKq2CknnkzDTlM64E6cUc8xGkXkxH8WMpj56kVMfAMMhb3yekM3aLnDdNPLj4c412qwfaYF7ox1WaJkE3mUNp6yzXPGgSCNkEWYR8gjzCBd05NRuy1dR5Sma@I8HUsYvkz@4eFbFq2qObPjz/RVG4PQZUuCxatNAaFOqHZbx6OKcpS6Upb29vUHexbdHmk5ag@9KuNOS4tLB6v@BLT@Bq42w4cQhvsLEYtLujQpdQfBuPEs4/AbqwnG2C4bVBf0v)

```scala
def f(n:Int):Int=if(n<4){if(n<2)1 else 0}else (n+1)*f(n-1)-(n-2)*f(n-2)-(n-5)*f(n-3)+(n-3)*f(n-4)
```

Ungolfed version.

```
object Main {
  def f(n: Int): Int = {
    if (n < 4) {
      if (n < 2) 1 else 0
    } else {
      (n + 1)*f(n-1) - (n - 2) *f(n-2) - (n - 5) *f(n - 3) + (n - 3)* f(n - 4)
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val tests = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
    val expected = Array(1, 0, 0, 2, 14, 90)
    val checker = Array("✕", "✓")

    for (index <- tests.indices) {
      val t = tests(index)
      val s = f(t)
      val e = expected(index)
      println(s"$t -> $s ${checker(if (s == e) 1 else 0)}")
    }
  }
}
```